# How to write new value to individual bit without (if/else) operator

Tags: c++, bit

I know that I can set bit N by:

```
VALUE |= 1 << N;
```

Or clear bit N by:

```
VALUE &= ~(1 << N);
```

But what is the most efficient way to "write" (not set or clear) bit N?
For example, I have a function:

```
__inline void writeBit(char &value, int N, bool state)
{
    if(state)
        value |= 1 << N;
    else
        value &= ~(1 << N);
}
```

Can I somehow get rid of if/else statements and instead do this only using binary and shift operators?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The page of [Bit Hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ConditionalSetOrClearBitsWithoutBranching) suggests using the following formula:

```
value ^= (-state ^ value) & (1 << N);
```

The declaration of `state` needs to change from `bool` to an `int`.

This trick works on computers with twos complement representation of negative numbers, because unary minus `-state` changes the state `1` to a number composed of ones, and leaves zero unchanged.

An alternative for superscalar CPUs looks like this:

```
value = (value & ~(1 << N)) | (-state & (1 << N));
```

Comment: Ok but if I try formula for superscalar CPU on "non superscalar", would it work?

Comment: @minyor Absolutely, it will work. It just wouldn't be as fast as the first formula.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for the simple solution:

```
inline void writeBit(char &value, int N, bool state)
{
   value &= ~(1 << N); // Unconditional clear. We don't care about old value.
   value |= char(state) << N; // Unconditional set to intended value. 
}
```

Since this is so clear and common, any decent optimizer will recognize the intent and use the best solution. Either of the two instructions will be useless, depending on `state`, but also harmless. That's better than the branch you have in your code.

I expect this to be better than either of dasblinkenlight's methods, unless an optimizer optimizes them all to the same.